# How to declare javascript variables a different way

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

How to declare variables this way:

```
var sarr = $("#crop_vals").find("input");
$(sarr).each(function() { 
    var $(this).attr("id") = $(this).val();
});
```

What I want is to have var named the id equivalent to the value.

Comment: You shouldn't do it but I'll say anyway; `window[ $(this).attr("id") ] = $(this).val();`, with no `var` statement.

Comment: +1. it is a valid question. The way you have it written though is invalid code. Running `JSLint` over it for example results in `Bad assignment. var $(this).attr("id") = $(this).val();` Using your existing code, the least amount of change to your coude to fix the issue would be `$(this).attr("id", $(this).val());`

Comment: Added an answer as all the other answers interpreted your question as "How do I set an ID?", whereas I read it as "How do I create a variable with the same name as the ID and set it to the value of the element with said ID?"

Comment: @Squirkle You could at least read a educational book like "Eloquent Javascript" to actually know what you're doing in practice.
OP check out http://eloquentjavascript.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the "variables" globally (though you shouldn't do this because it's asking for trouble)

```
var sarr = $("#crop_vals").find("input");
$(sarr).each(function() { 
    window[ this.id ] = this.value;
});
```

To set them in a safer way, you could do

```
var sarr = $("#crop_vals").find("input"),
    myVars = {};
$(sarr).each(function() { 
    myVars[ this.id ] = this.value;
});
```

and access with `myVars[ id ]`.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot set the attribute of an element that way, you are getting a value.

```
var $sarr = $("#crop_vals").find("input");

$sarr.each(function() { 
    this.id = this.value;
})
```

Note that as you have cached the objects, there is no need to use `$()` again.

Setting an attribute:

```
$(selector).attr('id', 'newValue');
```

Getting an attribute:

```
var id = $(selector).attr('id');
```

You can also use `attr` callback function:

```
$sarr.attr('id', function() { 
    return this.value;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `wrong syntax for assigning value` to attribute, you need to use `attr('attributeName', 'value');`

**Change**

```
var $(this).attr("id") = $(this).val();
```

**To**

```
$(this).attr("id", $(this).val());
```

You code will be

```
var sarr=$("#crop_vals").find("input");
$(sarr).each(function(){ 
     $(this).attr("id",$(this).val());
});
```

Comment: var $(this).attr("id",$(this).val()); uhh what?

Comment: Be sarcastic in the comments, not the answers.

Comment: I have updated my answer, There was problem in assignment of id.

Comment: Then don't just copy the code from the OP, and dump it into your answer *without editing* it :)

Comment: @Squirkle thanks for your suggestion but copy is one of the feature that is very difficult to avoid and useful most of times.

Comment: @Adil: +1 for least amount of code change to fix the original code: `$(this).attr("id", $(this).val());`. Off course, caching selectors upfront makes sense if they are used more than ones. i.e: `var $element = $(this));` then use it : `$element.attr("id", $element.val());`

Comment: Thanks @François Wahl, I had $(this).attr("id", $(this).val()); only missed var in the start.